# Difference between two Backbone.Router definitions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I to try create my first javascript app with backbone.js
And I found strange behaviour, don't understand difference between 2 piece of code
One works well and second seems not work.

That show alert on homepage and '#test' url

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "": 'index',
       "test": 'test'
    },
    index: function(){
        alert('index');
    },
    test: function(){
        alert('test');
    }    
});
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

And that not work, but `Backbone.history.hanlers` looks identical

```
var router = new Backbone.Router({
    routes:{
        "": 'index',
       "test": 'test'
    },
    index: function(){
         alert('index');
    },
    test: function(){
         alert('test');
    }    
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two bits of code is that in the first one you are creating a new class called `AppRouter` whereas in the second one you are just creating a plain `Backbone.Router` class.

I may be misunderstanding, but it seems you are saying that the first example works, and the second one doesn't?

The reason the second example does not work is because Backbone.Router only accepts the `routes` hash as an argument to it's constructor.  The `index` and `test` functions you have passed are not created as functions on the object.

If you want to pass the `routes` hash to the constructor you still need to extend Backbone.Router with the actual routing functions.  For example:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    index: function(){
        alert('index');
    },
    test: function(){
        alert('test');
    }    
});
var app = new AppRouter({ 
    routes:{
        "": 'index',
       "test": 'test'
    }});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: I saw the second example in "The Anatomy of BackboneJS". Can you say some why author use it? I can add source from there

Comment: @kiwaa I don't know why they'd use it, but if you look at the Backbone.Router constructor code (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-109) you can see that it doesn't do anything with functions that you pass in to it.  Maybe if you post the source I could answer that question.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Thanks for help